# What is a V-disparity image in Stereo vision and how is it generated

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

I am new to Stereo vision. I know what disparity and disparity map is. I couldn't understand the concept of V-disparity. Can someone explain how it can be generated and how can it be used for image stabilization?

Here is a sample image and its V disparity[image]

Answer (score 2):

Each row of the V-disparity image is a histogram of the various values of disparity that appeared on that row in the disparity map.

When done right, the disparities of the points on the ground plane will appear as a strong line in the V-disparity map.

When you are considering how to use it for stabilization, I suspect you should first consider what kinds of transforms you are trying to stabilize against.  E.g., are you trying to stabilize it against translations of the stereo rig that are up/down or left/right in the image plane?  Or are you more concerned about rotations of the stereo rig around the optical axis?

Each of these kinds of transforms will have different effects on that strong line.  If you can model what these effects will be for the different kinds of transforms, then you can achieve the stabilization.